# Java Math logic

Tags: java, math, logic

Hello I'm trying for the correct logic for the below statements.

- If ‘Bandwidth‘ is 250 or more below the 'Number of Users' (NumberOfUsers), then the VPN Status is 'A' (Bandwidth > NumberOfUsers+250)
- If ‘Bandwidth’ is between 'NumberOfUsers' and 250 below ‘NumberOfUsers’, then the Status is ‘B’ (Bandwidth between NumberOfUsers+1 to NumberOfUsers+249)
- If ‘Bandwidth’ is equal to or above 'NumberOfUsers', then the Status is 'C' (Bandwidth <= NumberOfUsers).

This is the code I tried

```
            if (bandwidthValue > numberofusersValue + 250) {
               setVpnStatus(A);
            } else if (bandwidthValue >= numberofusersValue+1    && bandwidthValue <= numberofusersValue + 249) {
                setVpnStatus(B);
            } else if (bandwidthValue <= numberofusersValue) {
                setVpnStatus(C);
            }
```

Testing

```
        User Entered - 
                    BandwidthValue      =   1234
                    NumberofUsersValue  =   900

        Vpn Status Expected By the user - C 
        PASSED

    User Entered - 
                BandwidthValue      =   1234
                NumberofUsersValue  =   1234

    Vpn Status Expected By the user - C 
    PASSED

    User Entered - 
                BandwidthValue      =   1236
                NumberofUsersValue  =   1234

    Vpn Status Expected By the user - B 
    Unable to set any status - FAILING
```

- Did not work for the third test cases.

Does the code above holds good for the values of BandwidthValue = x and NumberofUsersValue = y for these statements mentioned above?

Comment: To be fair I think using the word 'more' to describe something that is effectively 'more smaller' ie 'less'  is a potentially confusing use of english

Comment: Your wording sounds backwards on this. You say "‘Bandwidth‘ is 250 or more below the 'Number of Users'" and then use less than. This sentence of yours sounds to me like this: `NumberOfUsers - 250 > Bandwidth`.

Comment: But update with nested if isn't helping make the code readable. Instead of nested if, just use && with () round separate clauses as suggested, for readability, and then re-read the first requirement as 250 below number of users or more than 250 below number of users - does that help? Or look at it this way, more than 10 metres below the top of a mountain means you are well below the peak, not above it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following logic fulfils the requirement in your question:

```
if (bandwidthValue <= (numberofusersValue - 250)) {
    setVpnStatus(A);
} else if (bandwidthValue != numberofusersValue && (bandwidthValue - numberofusersValue <= 250)
                || (bandwidthValue > (numberofusersValue - 250) && bandwidthValue < numberofusersValue)) {
    setVpnStatus(B);
} else {
    setVpnStatus(C);
}
```

**Demo:**

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        // Tests
        System.out.println(getVpnStatus(1234, 900));
        System.out.println(getVpnStatus(1234, 1234));
        System.out.println(getVpnStatus(1236, 1234));
    }

    static char getVpnStatus(int bandwidthValue, int numberofusersValue) {
        char vpnStatus;
        if (bandwidthValue <= (numberofusersValue - 250)) {
            vpnStatus = 'A';
        } else if (bandwidthValue != numberofusersValue && (bandwidthValue - numberofusersValue <= 250)
                || (bandwidthValue > (numberofusersValue - 250) && bandwidthValue < numberofusersValue)) {
            vpnStatus = 'B';
        } else {
            vpnStatus = 'C';
        }
        return vpnStatus;
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
C
C
B
```

Feel free to comment in case of any issue/doubt.

Comment: Hello , Your logic fails for both the test cases, For the above test case USER expects the value C but for when BandwidthValue      =   1234 NumberofUsersValue  =   900.... as per you logic it is being set to A   , When bandwidth and the numberof users are same ie 1234 1234 as per the third statement it should be set to C but it is being set to B.......If ‘Bandwidth’ is equal to or above 'NumberOfUsers', then the Status is 'C' (Bandwidth <= NumberOfUsers).

Comment: @suryanandan - for first case (when BandwidthValue = 1234 NumberofUsersValue = 900) my logic was already giving the correct value, `C`. I have removed the `=` from the `else if` part and now it's also giving the correct output as per your requirement. I have posted a test code. Feel free to comment in case of any further doubt/issue.

Comment: Those two test cases have been passed, Now I'm testing with bandwidthValue 1236   numberofusersValue 1234 , with the user expecting the status to be set for B, .  the  statement logic is failing, Thanks

Comment: @suryanandan - Check my updated answer and let me know if there is any further issue/doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the code, I think I'd expect that to come out with A, but reading the problem description I would indeed expect C

I think the requirement has been misinterpreted - from the description, it sounds like  if users is say 1000 then bandwidth 750 or lower is A, 751 to 999 is B, 1000 or more is C. It looks like you have interpreted it the other way round.

Also the middle case needs && rather than ||

NOTE that the question appears to have been significantly edited and my answer may no longer be relevant, though it was when answered.

Comment: Is that the only change needed? changing || to &&

Comment: If you keep editing the question then the answer will make no sense and will not be helpful for anybody else. Read all the comments and ask yourself if just && will fix this.

Comment: Should I open a new question? Instead of editing the old one

Comment: I guess so, I'm no expert on stack overflow protocol but I think as it's generally a resource for people in the future looking for answers then editing a question too much after an answer will make it hard for that. I think at this stage though the problem is with interpreting the requirement rather than a code issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use parentheses `()`. e.g. `(numberOfUsersValue + 250)`

Answer (score 0):

A potential way of going about this based on your equations:

```
if(bandwidthValue > numberofusersValue + 250) { //Check largest baseline
  setVpnStatus(A);
} else if (bandwidthValue > numberofusersValue) { //Check second largest baseline
  setVpnStatus(B);
} else { //And finally use this for anything smaller
  setVpnStatus(C);
}
```